# How to take input from the middle of any sentence programmatically in java?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext

I'm developing an app similar to fill in the gap. I want to take input from a gap. The position of the gap will be measure automatically by this code.

```
 String Str = new String(text);
    System.out.print("Found Index :");
    System.out.println(Str.indexOf('_'));

    Log.e("Index", String.valueOf(Str.indexOf('_')));


    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    Paint textPaint = questionView.getPaint();
    textPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, Str.indexOf('_'), bounds);
    int height = bounds.height();
    int firstWidth = bounds.width();
    textPaint.getTextBounds(text, Str.indexOf('_') + 3, text.length(), bounds);
    int secondWidth = bounds.width();


    Log.e("String Bounds", "firstWidth " + firstWidth + " secondWidth " + secondWidth);


    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.setMargins(firstWidth, 0, secondWidth, 0);
    answerText.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

The output of this code is similar like this:

[image]

Now the problem arises. How can I set the length of the editText where the user can input to fill the gap?

I want to include that the whole sentence was "This is a sentence". The sentence will appear to the user like this "This is ___ sentence". I want to take input if the user touches the gap. We can also put a button like "Enter" to take input as well. How to do that correctly as now I can measure the width and height of the sentence.

Comment: Want some more explaination

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can implement TextEditMask or use this library

[Masked-Edittext](https://github.com/pinball83/Masked-Edittext)

Use :

```
MaskedEditText maskedEditText = new MaskedEditText(this,
                "This is ___ sentence",
                "_",
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_account_circle),
                new MaskedEditText.MaskIconCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onIconPushed() {
                        System.out.println("Icon pushed");
                        //Invoke here contact list or just clear input
                    }
                });
```